# Is it recommended to include composer.lock file in magento 2 extension?

Tags: magento2, composer

Is it recommended to include composer.lock file in magento 2 extension? I have a situation where our module is dependent on third-party dependencies. Sometimes we need to ask the merchants to run `composer update` to include the latest version of the dependency.

So, I am thinking to release a new version for the extension with the composer.lock with the exact dependencies required for the extension.

I have explored a lot of repositories on GitHub related to magento 2 but none of them included composer.lock in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Including the composer.lock file in your Magento 2 extension is a good practice that can help ensure compatibility and simplify the installation process for merchants. While many Magento 2 extension repositories on GitHub don't include the composer.lock file, it's important to note that this doesn't change the value of including it. Some developers may have simply forgotten to include it or not seen the benefit of doing so

Answer (score 0):

**No, it's not recommended.** First, we never add the composer.lock file our magento 2 extension because it uses our main composer.json and composer.lock file from our magento root path.

When your module is installed via composer at that time composer.json of your extension fetch and installed module. At the time your root composer.json and composer.lock file is automatically updated.

*If your module depends on any third-party module you should update it in two places.*

**1) Update your composer.json file.**

> **Hard dependencies** : A module with a hard dependency on another module cannot function without the module it depends on.

```
 "require": {
    "magento/module-catalog": "103.0.*",
    "magento/module-email": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-media-storage": "100.3.*",
    "magento/module-store": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-theme": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-ui": "101.1.*",
    "magento/module-variable": "100.3.*",
    "magento/module-widget": "101.1.*",
    "magento/module-authorization": "100.3.*"
   }
```

> **Soft dependencies** : A module with a soft dependency on another module can function properly without the other module, even if it has a dependency on the other module.

```
  "suggest": {
    "magento/module-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-graph-ql-cache": "*",
    "magento/module-store-graph-ql": "*"
  }
```

**2) Your module.xml file.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Magento_C" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_A"/>
        <module name="Magento_B"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

**[Click here to get more details](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/architecture/modules/dependencies/)**